# Invalid object type "GtkGrid" in gtk+ (C++)

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, glade

I am a newbie in GTK+ (C++) . As mentioned in documentation GtkGrid seems the best layout container . I can use it in code and in my .ui file to build and execute applications . But I can't find such thing in Glade or loading a .ui file which contains a GtkGrid in it . An error happens : "Unable to create object with type GtkGrid"
These are examples I am testing :
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html
Am I doing something wrong or there is a problem with Glade ? Thanks :)

+I'm using GTK+ 3.6.4 and Glade 3.8.5

Comment: How do you compile the code? What does `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` say?

Comment: It says 3.6.4 . I don't have problems with compiling code . There is nothing wrong with compiling and building . I just have problems with Glade interface designer . It doesn't contain GtkGrid !

Comment: sorry im with phone now . but  the .ui  file is exactly the same .ui file in this link :https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html